# Why does PhpStorm not recognize my import for Method and Template being used in Annotations?

Tags: php, symfony, import, annotations, phpstorm

I have a symfony 3.4 project in PhpStorm 2020.2. I import the following annotations

```
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
```

and use them, for example here:

```
/** @Route("/feedback/delete/{id}", name="feedbackDelete") @Method("DELETE") */
```

and

```
/** @Route("/dashboard", name="dashboard") @Template() */
```

Now PhpStorm tells me *Import 'Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method' is never used* - same for Template. That is not true, but why does PhpStorm not recognize it?

I use the plugins *PHP Annotations 7.1.3* and *Symfony Support 0.21.202*.

It's annoying because it always shows up in code analyses and I can't auto-optimize imports, because it breaks the code.

I thought, why bothering to ask - symfony 3.4 is old and I will probably soon migrate to symfony 5.X. But migration is a headache and since I recently talked with someone from a big symfony project where they still use 2.*, I thought there might actually be more people with this problem.

Comment: 1) PHP Annotations plugin is the one that handles that (it is the one that reports to PhpStorm "hey, this class is actually used here" as PhpStorm itself does not parse/support annotations). If it does not work: please check it with the plugin author if nothing else helps 2) Please also try with all other custom (not bundled by default) plugins disabled (and restart IDE): outdated plugins can case such issues 3) May also want to do "File | Invalidate Caches..." and restart IDE: in case if it's some issue with them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After experimenting a bit, I found the problem:

The PhpStorm plugin *PHP Annotations* does recognize the annotation, if it is starting in a new line of the PhpDoc. So while @Template is not recognized as used here:

```
/** @Route("/dashboard", name="dashboard") @Template() */
```

it works, if I change it to

```
/**
 * @Route("/dashboard", name="dashboard")
 * @Template()
 */
```

or even this is enough:

```
/** @Route("/dashboard", name="dashboard")
 *  @Template() */
```

I don't really like that since I like to keep my line count low and I don't see any advantage of putting this small annotation in a new line, but at least now I have a work-around.

I also opened an issue for this which can be found here: https://github.com/Haehnchen/idea-php-annotation-plugin/issues/211